# Deleting more tables at the same time & getting error when using ajax.response text

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, response

I have *two* problems.
**First one:**
I have a two tables in my database (`gmembers` and `groups`) and I want to check if a user quit from the group and there are no memebrs remaining in it delete that group. Firstly I collected every groups that has no members in an array called `junk`. Then I used a `for` loop to access every item of the `junk` array and delete from the database. But since I want to delete from two tables at the same time I had to use `JOIN`. I don't know why but this only delete from the `gmembers` table and nothing happens with the `groups` table.
I tried to tear it into two parts and delete once from the `gmembers` and then from the `groups` in another `sql` but I got the same result as I got with the `JOIN` one.
**Code:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST['action'] == "quit_group"){
    // Empty check
    if($gS == "" || $uS == ""){
        exit();
    }

    // Make sure already member
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM gmembers WHERE gname=? AND mname=? AND approved=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$gS,$uS,$one);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($numrows < 1){
        exit();
    }

    // Remove from the database
    $sql = "DELETE FROM gmembers WHERE mname=? AND gname=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$uS,$gS);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // If the group is empty remove from the database
    $junk = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM gmembers WHERE approved=? AND admin=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_result($zero,$zero);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        array_push($junk, $row["gname"]);
    }
    $stmt->close();

    for($i=0; $i<count($junk); $i++){
        // Delete from gmembers
        $groupa = $junk[$i];
        $sql = "DELETE * FROM gmembers gm JOIN groups gr ON gm.gname = gr.name WHERE gm.gname=? AND gr.name=?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$groupa,$groupa);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    echo "was_removed";
    exit();
}
?>
```

**Second One:**
I'm also having problems with `ajax.responseText`. When a group has been created and there are no erros I want to `header` the user to that groups that he/she has just created. So when everything is fine I `echo` the name of the group (`$name`) and the `was created` title. Then with javascript I check for these and I `header` them to the group page. But at this point my code fails. It only `echos group_created|example group` in an alert box and `window.location = "group.php?g="+sid;` does not work.
**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
// Create new group
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST['action'] == "new_group"){

    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
    $name = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['name']);
    $inv = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', $_POST['inv']);
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    if ($inv == "1"){
        $inv = "0";
    }
    if ($inv == "2"){
        $inv = "1";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM groups WHERE name=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $n_check = $stmt->num_rows;
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($name == "" || $inv == ""){
        echo "The form submission is missing values.";
        exit();
    } else if ($n_check > 0){ 
        echo "The group name you entered is alreay taken";
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($name) < 3 || strlen($name) > 50) {
        echo "Group name must be between 3 and 50 characters";
        exit(); 
    } else if (is_numeric($name[0])) {
        echo 'Group name cannot begin with a number';
        exit();
    } else {
        $stmt->close();
        // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        // Begin Insertion of data into the database
        // Add group to database
        $gicon = "group_icon.png";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO groups (name, creation, logo, invrule, creator)       
                VALUES(?,NOW(),?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$name,$gicon,$inv,$uS);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        // Add to group member to database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO gmembers (gname, mname, approved, admin)       
                VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$name,$uS,$one,$one);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        if (!file_exists("../groups")) {
            mkdir("../groups", 0755);
        }
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("../groups/$name")) {
            mkdir("../groups/$name", 0755);
        }
        $gLogo = '../images/group_icon.png';
        $gLogo2 = "../groups/$name/group_icon.png"; 
        if (!copy($gLogo, $gLogo2)) {
            echo "failed to create logo.";
        }
        echo "group_created|$name";
        exit();
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

The error handling, inserting, folder/file creating etc. works perfect except this line: `echo "group_created|$name";`
**JS Code:**

```
function createGroup(){
  var name = _("gname").value;
  var inv = _("invite").value;
  if(name == "" || inv == ""){
    alert("Fill in all fields");
    return false;
  }else{
    status.innerHTML = 'please wait...';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_parsers/group_parser.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true){
        var datArray = ajax.responseText.split("|");
        if(datArray[0] == "group_created"){
          var sid = datArray[1];
          window.location = "group.php?g="+sid;
        }else{
          alert(ajax.responseText);
        }
      }
    }
    ajax.send("action=new_group&name="+name+"&inv="+inv);
  }
}
```

Here I check for what `ajax` gives back and I `split` into two part the `echo "group_created|$name";` but the `window.location` function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For the Second One
Use:

```
window.Location.assign("group.php?g="+sid);
```

Or:

```
window.Location.replace("group.php?g="+sid);
```

Comment: Not really sure about your "DELETE '*' FROM" statement in your PHP consider changing it to "DELETE FROM", since there is no point using '*'(all). Even I think that the DELETE statement is not used with an '*'